# filter no dplyr utilizando uma variável categórica

Tags: r, dplyr

Suponha que eu tenho o seguinte conjunto de dados:

```
set.seed(12)
dados <- data.frame(grupos=rep(letters[1:5], 5), valores=rnorm(25))
head(dados)
  grupos    valores
1      a -1.8323176
2      b -0.0560389
3      c  0.6692396
4      d  0.8067977
5      e  0.2374370
6      a  0.7894452
```

Como eu poderia fazer para filtrar apenas as linhas cujos grupos são iguais a `a` ou `b`? Sei como filtrar as linhas iguais a um nível:

```
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  filter(grupos=="a")
  grupos    valores
1      a -1.8323176
2      a  0.7894452
3      a -0.9993864
4      a  0.3844801
5      a -1.3305330

dados %>%
  filter(grupos=="b")
  grupos     valores
1      b -0.05603890
2      b  0.37511302
3      b -0.03578014
4      b  0.65215941
5      b  1.64394981
```

Eu poderia fazer individualmente cada um dos filtros e juntá-los depois. Entretanto, meu problema original é mais complicado, pois é um data frame com 26.691 linhas, onde devo filtrar 1.116 valores diferentes. É impraticável filtrar cada um destes valores individualmente e combiná-los depois no final.

Comment: Você tentou: dados %>% 
  filter(grupos=="a"|grupos=="b")

Comment: Tentei sim. O problema é que são 1116 níveis diferentes que me interessam no meu conjunto de dados original. Pra utilizar esta solução, eu teria que escrever um código tipo `dados %>% filter(grupos=="a1"|grupos=="a2"|...|grupos=="a1116")`, o que acho impraticável.

Comment: Uma alternativa é usar regex, desde que identifique um padrão comum nos grupos que quer filtrar: Exemplo: dados<-dados[stringr::str_which(dados$grupos,"(a|b)"),]. Ou letras<-str_replace_all(toString(letters[c(1,2)]),",\\s","|");dados<-dados[stringr::str_which(dados$grupos,letras),]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesse caso você pode utilizar o `%in%`:

```
dados %>%
  filter(grupos %in% c("a", "b"))
   grupos valores
1       a -1.4806
2       b  1.5772
3       a -0.2723
4       b -0.3153
5       a -0.7777
6       b -1.2939
7       a -0.7035
8       b  1.1889
9       a  0.2236
10      b  2.0072
```